# Euphemism antonym

Tags: word-usage

I sent a club member an e-mail inquiring about a meeting that I was not informed about.  She reported it to others as "she shot me a note"!
Isn't that the opposite of a euphemism?

Comment: I would call it a "misunderstanding".

Answer (score 1):

*[Shoot s.o. a note/email](http://mbaintheusa.com/words-of-the-week-shoot-me-an-email/)* is slang, but the *shooting* does not imply violence or disrespect.

The opposite of a euphemism is a *[dysphemism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism)*, though this usage is not one. Just as the Greek prefix *eu-* means ‘good’, *dys-* means bad: think *dysfunction*.

An example would be military jargon for chipped beef on toast as *sh** on a shingle*. Using the abbreviation *SOS*, however, is a euphemism because it avoids referring to excrement.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up "euphemism." Based on the definition, I would say that this could be seen as the opposite (saying something light or mild in a harsh or blunt way,) but I would say that this expression is a fairly obvious metaphor, which I would say robs it of bluntness or harshness.

Answer (score 0):

shoot  [TFS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shoot) slang usage

> To give, send, or hand quickly:

As in:

*Shoot me that stapler. Shoot me a note.  Shoot me a beer while you are up.*